# What are the dimensions in angstrom of bacteria?

Tags: bacteriology, microscopy

I'm going to take a picture of a bacteria but I am unsure how large it is. What are the dimensions in angstrom of bacteria?

Comment: It varies. Is there a specific species or genus you're studying?

Comment: Helicobacter pylori @canadianer

Comment: if you know in microns then you can convert it into angstrom. But why angstrom. It is a very small unit for cellular dimension

Comment: I agree with @WYSIWYG since as far as I have seen its use is for measuring how far apart two molecules such as fluorophores are from each other in experiments such as FRET

Comment: @WYSIWYG it's used in protein structure accuracy

Comment: Usually you know the scale of the micrograph and measure the size of the object in it to get its size, not the other way round ;)

Comment: What has changed about this question to warrant a reopen?

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia: 3 um long with a diameter of 0.5 um. That equates to a length of 30 000 A and a diameter of 5 000 A.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicobacter_pylori